# Top level await in WebdriverIo Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to use top-level await with WebdriverIO but keep getting below error

> [0-0] import axios from 'axios'; [0-0] ^^^^^^ [0-0] [0-0] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module [0-0] at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18) [0-0] at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15) [0-0] at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27) [0-0] at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) [0-0] at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) [0-0] at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) [0-0] at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:190:29) [0-0] at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25) [0-0] at async Promise.all (index 0) [0-0] at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)

If I include "type": "module" in the package.json
I get below error

> ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: /Users/anilp/custom-folder/experiments/wdio-mocha-sync/wdio.conf.js: require() of ES Module /Users/anilp/custom-folder/experiments/wdio-mocha-sync/wdio.conf.js from /Users/anilp/custom-folder/experiments/wdio-mocha-sync/node_modules/@wdio/config/build/lib/FileSystemPathService.js not supported.
> wdio.conf.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
> Instead rename wdio.conf.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/anilp/custom-folder/experiments/wdio-mocha-sync/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

Framework: Mocha + WebdriverIO

```
import axios from 'axios';

// top-level await: Node >= v14.8.0 with ESM test file
const tests = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/users", {
      headers: {
          Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
      }
  });
    resolve(response.data)
  });


describe('My Login application', () => {
    tests.forEach((d) => {
        it(`correctly print details of ${d.login} args`, function() {
          console.log(d);
        });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same thing and found this PR https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/pull/6812.
Looks like wdio doesn't have support for top-level await yet. May be in version 8..